# Trouble instantiating ColDef variable

Tags: typescript, ag-grid-angular

I am struggling w creating a local variable in TypeScript.
The ColDef is a type found in the agGrid.

I can create an array of ColDefs w/ just one entry and then grab that...
But I can not seem to arrive at the correct syntax for simply

```
    import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';

foo(){

    let try1 = new ColDef(  {field : this.fieldName}); //get error
    let try2 = new ColDef(   this.fieldName );  //get error 
    const try3 = new ColDef(   this.fieldName );  //get error 

   
    let myCDs : ColDef[] = [
            {field : this.fieldName}
          ];
    let myCD : ColDef = myCDs[0];  //and yet this works...  

}
```

regardless of what I try, i get

ERROR in src/app/helpers/agGrid/AgColDef.ts(20,31): error TS2693: 'ColDef' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

What is the correct syntax to declare just 1 ColDef object?

(i realize this is a newbie TS question, so tyia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an `Interface` Like a `class`.

export **interface** *ColDef* extends AbstractColDef, IFilterDef
[ColDef github](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/e4eee61d870209418361f9bbea0e4a2358e1f1aa/community-modules/core/src/ts/entities/colDef.ts)

*If you want to create one object for an interface:*

```
let obj: ColDef = { /* properties */ }
```

This works because the created object just needs the specified set of properties in ColDef interface.

Comment: vaira - where did you go to decide ColDef is an interface?  I have been all over the handbook and I never really see a declaration. 
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-properties/
It would be good to see a declaration.  Right now my class returns a ColDef,  it might be better to 'BE' a ColDef and just implement the definition.

Comment: I have attached the link in the answer already, in the same file line 104 you can see its a interface.
The handbook is not for telling what in the implementation underneath, you can only find it  in repositories or in your project you can figure out from module.

Comment: i overlooked that link, thanks again,